# Shifting to Applied Math from Civil Engineering

Tags: mathematics, engineering

I recently Graduated. My major was Civil Engineering. I want to apply for an Applied math Ph.D. My undergraduate thesis was on continuum mechanics that use heavy tensor machinery. Would any applied math Ph.D. program in the US take students from an Engineering background?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "that use heavy tensor machinery" most likely not, if you define your thesis in these terms. Applied math **is** that machinery: by calling it machinery it looks like either it is a black box for you, or that you mildly despise it...

Answer (score 2):

Your question is akin to "Does the Nobel Prize committee consider nominees of Spanish nationality?". It is easy to verify empirically that the answer is "yes", but of course this gives little certainty to anyone from Spain who may have been nominated for a Nobel Prize about whether they will actually get it.  What matters, of course, is whether the nominee is *qualified*, and that is true for your case as well.

The question for you to answer is then "Have I taken enough mathematics courses to be competitive with applicants who are mathematics undergraduates?", "How have I done in these classes?", "Are there other ways in which I can demonstrate that I am qualified?"

Answer (score 2):

As @WolfgangBangerth observes, tautologically they will *consider* you, but the question is about your competitiveness against other applicants. Not that everything is some sort of bloodthirsty competition, but, rather, that each program has limited resources, both faculty and money to support students.

In the U.S., in my observation, the notion of "applied math program" varies greatly. Some programs do allow fairly narrow focus within mathematics, and huge emphasis on the engineering and scientific applications, while others do not see "applied math" as being wildly different from "math". Indeed, the traditional notion that applied math is numerical solution of PDEs is a bit narrow-archaic, now that we have crypto, coding, big data, machine learning, etc.

In particular, to avoid spending toooo much on application fees to programs that are not a good fit for you, you'll need to look at the individual programs. They are not all the same. Some might value your engineering experience, while others might worry about your limited mathematical experience.